# Is there a online filter to check email attachments?

Tags: email, virus

I've just received an email from an old employer. There is very little information in the message sent just:

> See attached file for your review.
>
> Kind regards, Mick

with an attachment. I would like to validate the email attachment but I am afraid by clicking on it I will inadvertently download something malicious.

I've read about downloading a virtual machine to open it for me but I don't want to download that on the work PC. Is there another way check?

Comment: you could scan the file with your work PC's anti-virus or upload to an online virus scanner like virustotal?

Comment: Hey thanks ive been looking into that, but ive Norton doesnt seem to have a smiple scan file before downloading function

Comment: Ah. You want something to scan before you download. This might not be necessary. It's ok to download as long as you do not open. Run Norton as normal.

Comment: Thanks champ, I ve manage to find out that Norton has a email protection built in, whether it has actually worked time will tell, as for the attachment it was spam.

Answer (score 2):

[Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/) and [malwr](https://malwr.com/) and both good sites to submit suspicious files. Virus total will tell you if the file is flagged by any antivirus. Malwr will give you more detailed analysis (this may/may not be of interest to you).

Note that you're submitting files to an online community, so don't submit anything that is potentially proprietary/secret.

Comment: malwr is currently, as at comment date, unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to ring your ex-employer and ask them is they sent you the email.

If they say no, then you know it is a virus or similar and delete it with no further thought.

If they say yes then you can go ahead and scan the attachment for a virus.